# how to sort data in jarray with where clause in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have a jarray.I get it like below

```
string JSONresults;
            JSONresults = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
            JArray v = JArray.Parse(JSONresults);
            int arrayCount = v.Count();
            Debug.WriteLine("count of the array is :"+arrayCount);

            //var sorted = from p in v
            //             where
```

now I want to get only sorted data according to the user selection like we do in `XElement` with `where(x=> x.Element("Ship-cd").value=="somevalue")`. how can do it with this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Could you provide example input with the according output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class with properties that you need:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string ShipCD { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

Then you need to cast your `Jarray` into a `List<YourClass>`.

```
List<YourClass> l = v.Select(x => new YourClass {
    ShipCD = (string)x["Ship-cd"],
    // Other properties
}).ToList();
```

You can see an example [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithLinq.htm).

Then you can use `Where` to filter the list:

```
l = l.Where(x => x.ShipCd == "somevalue").ToList();
```